# How to set new Id of div using its old id dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set new id to div using its old Id?

```
$("#oldId").attr("id","newId");
```

Its not working.

Comment: In what way is the 'new id' dependent on the 'old id'?

Comment: Actually it is working http://jsfiddle.net/CThbJ/

Comment: It seems to be [working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/CEB5Z/). Do you have any other JavaScript errors?

Comment: No its totally different. but i want to change it dynamically.

Comment: Can you show that online or create a fiddle. I guess you need to enclose that in jQuery ready function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jY8TA/ It IS working, something else is messing with you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple JS

```
document.getElementById("PreviousName").id="CurrentName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine, though as of jQuery 1.6 you are encouraged to use `prop` over `attr` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for discussion).

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').prop('id', 'test2');
    $('#test2').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GNTZa/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question. [Can I change the ID of an HTML element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787369/can-i-change-the-id-of-an-html-element-using-javascript) Make sure you re-execute your jquery function after the change. Maybe you're working on a 'cached' javascript-object, not the DOM object.